# Performing a calculation but only getting NaN as a result

Tags: c#

```
public double calculateStdErrorEst()
{
    double see = 0;
    double residualSquare = 0;
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    List<double> residualTotal = new List<double>();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stockPctReturns.Count; i++)
        {
            // square root of all sums of predicted - actual or market - stock
            residualSquare = Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble((marketPctReturns.ElementAt(i) - stockPctReturns.ElementAt(i)), culture));
            residualTotal.Add(Math.Round(residualSquare, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }

        see = residualTotal.Sum() / (stockPctReturns.Count - 2);
        see = Math.Sqrt(see);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return Math.Round(see, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to round the values down so I can keep the numbers small to work with them but no matter what I have tried, I keep getting `NaN` as the only result. Am I missing something here?

Comment: what is stockPctReturns and whats the count?

Comment: Best guess: you're trying to get `Math.Sqrt` from negative value.

Comment: The `Math.Sqrt` method returns `NaN` for negative numbers.

Comment: It is a list of percent changes from the day before and it is roughly 2100 items in total. I believe a negative number is probably what causes it but is there no way of getting around that?

Comment: `I'm trying to round the values down so I can keep the numbers small to work with them`... So 1.0 is more workable than 1.4 ?

Comment: NaN is for Sqrt of  < 0.  You can do absolute value get your square and throw sign on after the fact, but I'm not sure why you need the sqrt in the first place.  You have many potential problems in that try catch, what if marketPctReturns and stockPctReturns are not same length?, what if value cannot be converted to double, etc... I'd step through it if I were stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably trying to get square root from negative value, which causes `Math.Sqrt` to return `double.NaN`. Use `Math.Abs` before calling `Math.Sqrt`:

```
residualSquare = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble((marketPctReturns.ElementAt(i) - stockPctReturns.ElementAt(i)), culture)));
```